# ios restarting VPN connection with ondeamand roule

Tags: swift, vpn, restart, tunnel, ondemand

i have app that using von configuration to open packet tunnel provider
and i try to use dynamic dns
so every change of network i use NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences function
and from some reason its make the tunnel crash and and when the tunnel start again (because on demand rule .any) ,i use method to get device dns servers and set the on the tunnel setting
this sims to be work but in the end i see that its make the tunnel to crash
i used on demand rule .any to make the vpn stay alive
there is any elegant and legal way to restart vpn without app (only form the extension) to make this work with out crashing ?